# existing project has no content_main

Tags: android-studio

I am using a sample android BLE project as a learning tool but the project has no `content_main.xml` which, if I understand, is the representation of the layout as an image.

The `activity_main.xml` is there, but I don't want to hand carve the layout.

Is there a way I can 'recover' or generate the content_main.xml?

Comment: If you accidentally deleted the `content_main.xml` Follow these steps, Right click on `layout` folder and click in `Show History`. You can recover your past changes from here

Comment: Thanks for responding. The sample project did not have a content_main.xml when I opened it. I have made no changes, so will have no history.

Comment: Its ok content_main.xml is just an another separate xml it will include in main xml, instead of doing separate xml files, we can write it entire view inside activity_main.xml itself, Hence I think your sample project contains all  the view inside activity_main.xml.

Comment: Maybe I am asking the wrong question. I expected in Android Studio to be able to view a graphic representation the screen where I could place buttons, text field etc. That is what I cannot find, and I had linked that to the content_main.xml.